# How to get the selected items on Source Control History window when creating a Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I develop a **Visual Studio extension**. I attached a button to the Source Control History Window's Context Menu *(the menu with 'changeset details', 'compare', etc.. on it)*

I need to get the **selected History items** from the window, but couldn't figure it out how to do it.

**Update:**

I'm using team foundation server as source control. Here's the screenshot of the window i want to access to. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxdTQ.png)

I have found a way to retrieve the window object's data, but i still have some issues:

```
package.FindToolWindow(typeof(/*I don't know the type of the window*/), 0, false);
```

*(package is instance of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package class)*

What is the type of the Source Control History window (the one on the screenshot)? This is the missing part of the puzzle i think.

Please help :)
Thanks.

Comment: Which kind of source control tool did you use? Could you share a screen shot about the window you want to the menu/history items?

Comment: I've updated the question: I've used TFS source control.

Comment: @Belian did you ever get this working? I'm trying to do something similar with the Visual Studio Git history (and probably also eventually TFS/DevOps). [My question is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504005/visual-studio-extension-get-reference-to-currently-selected-item-in-git-histor)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful for your needs:
[Tool Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567.aspx)

I dont know your other code parts, but I guess you initiate a window application, where you want to render the history list. 
This window application needs:

```
private FirstToolWindow window;
private void ShowToolWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
     window = (FirstToolWindow) this.package.FindToolWindow(typeof(FirstToolWindow), 0, true); 
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll check it out!

Comment: No, my goal would be to get the actually selected history items from the history window. So i want to retrieve some data (to be more precise, i want the **selected history items changeset ids**)